# Firebase Database Query Error : child is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a table `users` in Firebase with these data

```
{
  "users" :
  [
   {"id": 1,
     "fcmToken" : "APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7hdiWY78iar8s:APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7h",
     "fName" : "John",
     "lName" : "Doe",
     "phone" : "9786770861"
   },
   {"id": 2,
     "fcmToken" : "APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7hdiWY78iar8s:APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7h",
     "fName" : "Jane",
     "lName" : "Doe",
     "phone" : "6178779690"
   }

 ]
}
```

after import I get this

[image]

I tried to query it using NodeJS

```
/*================================
=            Database            =
================================*/

var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require('/Users/john/Desktop/Apps/APNS/node/mhn-app-firebase-adminsdk-bs45c-5ac3770488.json');

var firebase = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://mhn-app.firebaseio.com"
});



var db = firebase.database();
var users = db.child('users');
var query = users.orderByChild('fcmToken');

console.log(users);
```

I kept getting this error :

```
⚡️  node  node app.js                                                           
/Users/john/Desktop/Apps/APNS/node/app.js:17                                  
var users = db.child('users');                                                 
               ^                                                               

TypeError: db.child is not a function                                          
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/john/Desktop/Apps/APNS/node/app.js:17:16)   
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)                                      
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)                        
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)                                          
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)                                        
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)                                 
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)                              
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)                                      
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

> db.child is not a function

I followed the exact syntax from Firebase tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WTQZV5-roY

Look at **4:33** minutes you will see it

[image]

I hope someone can shed some lights on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where did you find this example (apparently from the YouTube Firebase channel !??) but the `child()` method is a method of a [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference), not of the [`Database`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Database).

You should therefore do:

```
var db = firebase.database();
var users = db.ref().child('users');
var query = users.orderByChild('fcmToken');
```

or directly:

```
var db = firebase.database();
var users = db.ref('users');
var query = users.orderByChild('fcmToken');
```

Comment: We should report this error to the Firebase team. Will add a comment below the video.

Comment: If I want to see those 2 records in console, how do I do it ? https://i.imgur.com/ZTNel0N.png

Comment: Have a look at the doc of a DataSnapshot https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot and use `snap.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {})`